# System::String reference to C++ char* parameter

Tags: c++, string, reference, c++-cli

Is there an direct way to manage C++/CLI Strings in a wrapper to char* parameter for native C++ method?!

example:

```
void Test::TestFunc(System::String ^%str)
{
    // right conversion to char* and consider the reference
}
```

native C++ function:

```
void TestB::Func(char *str)
{
    ...
}
```

my tricky way:

```
void Test::TestFunc(System::String ^%szRecvBuffer)
{   
    pin_ptr<const wchar_t> szRecvBufferP = PtrToStringChars(szRecvBuffer);

    // Convert to a char*
    size_t origsize = wcslen(szRecvBufferP) + 1;
    const size_t newsize = 100;
    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    char nstring[newsize];
    wcstombs_s(&convertedChars, nstring, origsize, szRecvBufferP, _TRUNCATE);
    strcat_s(nstring, " (char *)");

    char *szRecvBufferCh = nstring;

    m_object->TestCommand(szRecvBufferCh); // parameter char*
    System::String ^tmp = gcnew System::String(szRecvBufferCh); 
    szRecvBuffer = tmp;
}
```

greets leon22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a lot manually that the runtime will take care of for you.

```cpp
void Test::TestFunc(String^% szRecvBuffer)
{
    using System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal;

    IntPtr memHandle = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(szRecvBuffer);
    try
    {
        char* const str = static_cast<char*>(memHandle.ToPointer());
        m_object->TestCommand(str);
        szRecvBuffer = gcnew String(str);
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(memHandle);
    }
}
```

If you're using VC++ 2010, you can use `std::unique_ptr<>` with a custom deleter to avoid using `try..finally`, ultimately cutting the number of lines of code in half.

Answer (score 2):

If the `char*` is an output parameter, then in C++/CLI you must pass `System::StringBuilder^`

Comment: Could you describe that, please!?

Comment: @Armen : This would be true for P/Invoke, but I don't see any P/Invoke signatures in the OP's code, and using P/Invoke from C++/CLI would be downright silly to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for "System::String" with Google, the second link is [How to convert from System::String* to Char* in Visual C++](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311259) . This is obviously a FAQ!

(There appear to be about 5 different ways depending on the specifics of the conversion required, so I won't summarise them here: go read the article.)

Comment: Yes, I know this article. But how would you handle the reference (need the answer of function into the string) -> same as in my tricky way?!

Comment: I'm out of my CLI depth in that case! I have to admit that I don't quite understand your question: "need the answer of function into the string" doesn't parse for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid having conversions in both directions, because `System::String` uses `wchar_t`, and a Unicode->Multibyte conversion is necessary to get `char` from that.

But `marshal_as` should make the conversion much easier.

Comment: I don't think `marshal_context` comes with a specialization for `char*`, only `char const*`, but it would certainly be trivial to write one